# Laying ceramic or porcelain tile over concrete covered with very thin black mastic

Tags: tile

With a 4" razor scrapper I have removed all but a very thin transparent layer of the black mastic. It is very smooth and there is no rough or poroused concrete exposed. Will thinset stick to the floor without first using some type of primer to help the thinset stick? If so what's it called and is there a better type of thinset to use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are. Read the back of the bags of thinset, you will find their list of accepted substrate to go over.

Yours will be "asphalt cutback"

It sounds as if you have it scraped down far enough

Here is the [online pdf](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/48/48d29775-6ce8-465f-a7f2-6bab0aed0e67.pdf) of the floor prep you need. It is on the second page